# $\| f \|_\infty>A,$ then there exists a set $\mu (E)>0$ such that $|f(x)|>A$.

Tags: measure-theory

> **6.T** (Bartle's book) If $\| f \|_\infty>A,$ then there exists a set $E \in \mathcal A$ such that $\mu (E)>0$ and such that $|f(x)|>A$ for all $x \in E$.

How to prove this? Since $\|f\|_{\infty} = \inf_{N\in \mathcal A,\ \mu(N) = 0} \{\sup_{x\not\in N} |f(x)|\}$, given $N\in \mathcal A$ with $\mu(N) =0$, we have $A< \|f\|_{\infty}\leq \sup |f(x)|$ for $x\not\in N$. So we cannot have $|f(x)| < A$ for all $x\not\in N$, otherwise it would follow $\sup|f(x)| \leq A< \sup |f(x)|,$ contradiction. So for every $N, \mu(N)$ we may find a $x_N\not\in N$ such that $|f(x_N)|>A$. Now what? I can't proceed. I tried to define $E = \{x_N: N, \mu(N)=0\}$ to try to collect all such $x_N$ but I cannot ensure that it is measurable.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E=\{x:|f(x)| >A\}$. This set belongs to $ \mathcal A$. If $\mu (E)=0$ then $|f| \leq A$ a.e. and this implies that $\|f\|_{\infty} \leq A$, a contradiction.